# Convert strings of assignments to dicts in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following strings - they are assignment commands:

```
lnodenum = 134241
d1 = 0.200000
jobname = 'hcalfzp'
```

Is there a way to convert this string, containing variables and values, to keys and values of a dictionary? It'd be equivalent to executing the below command:

```
my_dict = dict(lnodenum = 134241, d1 = 0.200000, jobname = 'hcalfzp')
```

I guess this is one way to do it:

```
my_str = """lnodenum = 134241
            d1 = 0.200000
            jobname = 'hcalfzp' """
exec('my_dict = dict(%s)' % ','.join(my_str.split('\n')))
```

Not sure whether anyone would think of a more concise way?

Note: I am using my own code for scientific computing, so I don't mind having code with safety concerns like malicious input data. But, I do prefer to have code that is shorter and easier to read :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need for `exec`. Just use a regular assignment with the `dict` function.

```
my_str = """lnodenum = 134241
            d1 = 0.200000
            jobname = 'hcalfzp' """
my_dict = dict(pair for pair in (line.strip().split(' = ') for line in my_str.splitlines()))
```

Result:

```
>>> my_dict
{'d1': '0.200000', 'lnodenum': '134241', 'jobname': "'hcalfzp'"}
```

Or, if you'd like to parse each object, use `ast.literal_eval` with a comprehension:

```
import ast
my_dict = {k:ast.literal_eval(v) for k,v in (line.strip().split(' = ') for line in my_str.splitlines())}
```

Result:

```
>>> my_dict
{'d1': 0.2, 'lnodenum': 134241, 'jobname': 'hcalfzp'}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment! The drawback of this is the integers and floats become strings, though.

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you so much.